# Negative edge weights in Dijkstra and Bellman Ford shortest path algorithms

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

The main difference between Dijkstra algorithm and Bellman Ford algorithm that all texts (including CLRS) specify is that Dijkstra's algorithm need all non negative edge weights, while Bellman Ford algorithm can work with and detect -negative edge cycles.

However I feel a bit different, especially after coming across problem asking to build shortest path tree from node $a$ in following graph:

[image]

My shortest path tree after running Dijkstra came like this:

[image]

Then why texts say that Dijkstra need all non negative edge weights?
I feel that it should be no -ve edge weight cycle reachable from source node. 
Am I correct with this? or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Then why texts say that Dijkstra need all non negative edge weights?

Because it has to work for *all* cases, not only a few examples.

> I feel that it should be no -ve edge weight cycle reachable from source node.

Try proving that claim and see where it leads. If you're successful, great; if not, trying to prove the opposite will fix your intuition.

See also [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/19775/98) for a high-level argument.

> The smallest example where Dijsktra fails has four nodes, no (directed) cycle at all, and no negative-value cycle:
>  [image: example graph]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75020/discussion-on-answer-by-raphael-negative-edge-weights-in-dijkstra-and-bellman-fo).

Comment: "The smallest example where Dijkstra fails has **three** nodes"  $s\stackrel{4}{\longrightarrow}p$, $p\stackrel{-3}{\longrightarrow}q$, $s\stackrel{2}{\longrightarrow}q$

Answer (score 2):

Raphael's answer is spot on, but let me offer some additional perspective as well.

> Then why texts say that Dijkstra need all non negative edge weights?

Because we've been unable to prove it works otherwise.

In fact, imagine that negative edge-weights were allowed. In one extreme, this means that *all* edge weights can be negative. So we could take any graph that we want, make all weights equal to -1, and give it to the algorithm and find a shortest path between $s$ and $t$. This shortest path maximizes the length of the path (in terms of the number of edges), so we'll get a Hamiltonian path between $s$ and $t$ if it exists. But as far as we know, there is no polynomial-time algorithm for solving the problem!

Comment: Came across surprising fact when watching a video. At [10:43](https://youtu.be/2raV0H9KqY8?t=10m43s), it shows graph with -ve edge on which Dijkstra works. At [12:01](https://youtu.be/2raV0H9KqY8?t=12m1s), it shows graph with -ve edge on which Dijkstra does not works. Surprising fact is: in all cases shortest path tree is formed, but the incorrectness lies in the fact that, in 2nd graph, node gets relaxed **again after** the iteration in which it is extracted from Q, which is not desired and considered incorrect in Dijkstra!!! This is explained at [12:54](https://youtu.be/2raV0H9KqY8?t=12m54s)

Comment: Can you confirm that this is indeed what I was missing: shortest path tree will be formed in all graphs without -ve edge cycles, but might be that a node will get relaxed after it has been extracted from Q which is considered wrong in Dijkstra?

Comment: @anir No, Dijkstra (as [quoted by you](https://postimg.org/image/5rj3vjbgf/) never does this. Whoever does this is using the algorithm wrong.

Comment: @anir It's not at all surprising that Dijkstra will work on *some* graphs with negative edge weights.